# How to populate fields with related values from another table in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a column of values that says `White`, `Black`, `Red`, `Blue`, etc. I would like that row to convert to the colours' ID instead of the colour name. For example, `White` will be `1`, `Black` will be `2` and so on.

I have almost 20 such values of colours corresponding with their IDs and I've heard that nested IF statements in Excel doesn't go beyond 7 IFs. How can I populate that column with the values' IDs instead of the values themselves?

Comment: There is `VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,[range_lookup])` and `INDEX(array,MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_array,[match_type])`. Now you need to show the example of your data to get the exact formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `switch` function (supports 126 values):

Example:

`=SWITCH(A2,1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday","No match")`

Complete documentation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SWITCH-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e